# How do I include the number of subscribers I have in my website automatically in Mailchimp?

Tags: javascript, html, web, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am a beginner in using Mailchimp. I really don't know what I am doing in Mailchimp. But I do know HTML, CSS, and Javascript. I have used MailChimp, to track the number of subscribers I have. Now I want to include MailChimp's API to show the number of my subscribers in my website. I just want to show the number of Subscribers. I don't want to show their contact for their own security. Is there any way to show that in my website? Any way at all? Please don't close my question just because it seems stupid (if it is.) because I am new at this stuff and I really don't even know if what I am saying even makes sense to you.
Conclusion= How do I show the number of subscribers in my website from Mailchimp?

Comment: It's not a stupid question, it's just incomplete (no coding attempt), and something you should be asking MailChimp or could probably find in their [docs](https://mailchimp.com/developer/marketing/api/lists/).

Comment: @wazz I really did try to find out something. Even on google. and Youtube. But all people do these days is Mailchimp to Wordpress